# how to remove Quotation mark using regex

Tags: java, regex

how can I remove Quotation mark using regex? I tried to implement it to the replace in strings but I went outside the like adding a string. I dont know how to replace it I just want to take all the Quotation mark and replace it with blank string

```
data.replace(""", ")
```

that one wont work

Comment: What have you tried? It's hard to find the problem in your solution when we can't see anything.

Comment: Why you need to use regex? why you don't simply call `replace("\"", "");`?

Comment: @mabbas That is `Question mark`. Not `Quotation mark` :)

Answer (score 5):

you need to escape the quote with a '\'

```
String quoted = "\"quoted text\"";
quoted.replace("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the quotes first!

To replace using a regex do this:

```
"\"This is some text\"".replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

In regex, `'` is a [metacharacter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) , hence you have to escape it with a `\`

try this :

```
str = str.replaceAll("\'", "");
```

or for a double quote:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\"", "");
```